# Importing .fbx results in triangulation

Tags: modeling, import, topology

What causes a Quad mesh to be triangulated when importing it in blender and how can I avoid it?

(note: the .fbx export was done in 3ds Max with correct settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the export dialog, not only uncheck *Triangulate* but also *Preserve edge orientation*. This option is here to avoid issue on non-quads i think.

Comment: Unchecking Preserve edge orientation did the trick.
Thanks!